# Uploadpath CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

I have created an uploads folder in the CodeIgniter root, that accepts all the uploaded images from the form. Then the upload path is sent to the database. Later i retrieve all the information from the database in a view page. I am trying to get all the images to display on the view page that are uploaded, but the upload path is adding too much to the URL.

the upload config looks like this:

```
$config = array(
        'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size'  => '6000',
        'max_width' => '2068',
        'max_height'    => '1032',
        'encrypt_name'  => true,
);
```

and the view page looks like this:

```
                                             <tr>                
                                                 <td><img src="<?php echo $pet->filepath?          
                                                     >" alt="pet photo"></img><br/></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->pet_name?><br/>      
                   </td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->species."      "; 
               ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->breed; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->gender; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->color; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $pet->comments; ?></td>


                                            </tr>

                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

when i check the image URL when i test the view it shows up as:
CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php/upload/uploads/beagle.jpg

but it needs to be:
CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/uploads/beagle.jpg

does anyone know how to change this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy to follow tutorial [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) that explains how to create a URL rewrite that removes the index.php. You could edit it to be something like this (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/(index\.php|uploads.*|robots\.txt).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then you should (again, not tested), be able to access the image at `CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/uploads/beagle.jpg`

EDIT: woops, misunderstood the question, you want `CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/index.php/upload/uploads/beagle.jpg` -> `CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/uploads/beagle.jpg` right?

In that case, give this a shot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*/index.php/upload/uploads(.*)$ /CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/uploads$1 [L]
```

This says any url that contains /index.php/upload/uploads should redirect to `/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/CodeIgniter_2.1.0/uploads/whatever`

Comment: do i just copy and paste that code directly into the view .htacess file in the view?

Comment: Theres a simple htaccess rewrite tutorial [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php), give it a shot.

Comment: do i need to add 
     Options +FollowSymlinks
to the beginning of the .htaccess?

I've tried multiple combinations, and the file still won't display because its still looking for the wrong URL

Comment: Well, its entirely possible that that rewrite doesnt work 100%, like I said, its not tested. All it is saying is 'anything that does not contain index, uploads, or robots should go to /index.php/whatever'. I will edit it a little bit in a second

Comment: thanks so much. i am pretty familiar with how the MVC flow works now, but when it comes to htaccess rewrite and URL redirecting I am clueless.

Comment: Well, there is likely another way of doing it, the problem you are having is that `$pet->filepath' is linking you to the upload controller. I would help you with that code as well, but I would need to see what you have for your controller code. Give the above rewrite a shot (I personally think rewrite are easier than customizing CI), and let me know how it goes. And if I helped, don't forget to mark it as a correct answer :D

Comment: hmmm. typed it into the root .htaccess file. everything looks right. i am not sure what i am doing wrong. do i need to call the .htaccess file from the view or anything? or are the rules applied to the entire MVC application as a whole automatically?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess? It should be in your root dir (the one with index.php in it)

Comment: it is in my root dir.

i figured it out though. all i did was this

      <img src="<?php echo base_url().$pet->filepath?>" alt="pet      photo"></img>

i just added base_url(). to the beginning and it worked perfectly! thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: i have another question though. when i upload the photos. it gives them a random name like "107fb08f4a11cc37a040237cdcf0e48a.jpg"   how do i disable this function so that it uploads them as their original file name from the hard drive?

Comment: Try setting `encrypt_name` to false? ;) Glad you figured it out! I wouldnt mind an upvote too by the way, since you are at 17 rep :D